# How can I import certain files from a folder by creating a mask?

Tags: python, for-loop, masking, astropy

I'm incredibly new to coding so please bear with me
so basically I have a folder of 4,229 .fits files (legac_spec) and a dataframe (legac_cat) with 1989 rows, two of the columns being id number and mask value. Each .fits file has a file name of something along the lines of `legac_M[mask value]_v3.6_spec1d _[id number].fits` but I'm not sure how to get the specific files I need where each mask value and id number corresponds to a specific file.

I know I need to use a for loop but I'm not sure how I get it to do what i need it to do since I have to mask the mask value and id numbers separately

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from astropy.io import fits

legac_cat = pd.read_csv('legac_file')

M = legac_cat['mask']
ID = legac_cat.id

directory_name = 'C:/Users/kfdhfs/Downloads/legac_spec'
for mask_val in legac_cat['mask']:
     for files in directory_name:
          hdu = fits.open(files)
```

Comment: You can build the filename using one of a number of possible string formatting techniques (the answer below gives one valid possibility).  Also the line `for files in directory-name:` definitely isn't what you want.  Python has no way to assume that an arbitrary string represents a directory name.  If you want to iterate over all fits files in a directory you can use something like: `for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_name, '*.fits'))`.  But in this case it isn't even necessary since what you really want is to generate the filenames yourself from data in the table, I think...

Answer (score 1):

I've barely ever used Pandas. I haven't tested this solution, so sorry if it doesn't work "straight out of the box". It seems to me that all you have to do is iterate over your dataframe's rows (where each row has a "mask" and "id" that correspond to one file), and then construct a filename from each row's "mask" and "id" - then open the file:

```
legac_cat = pd.read_csv("legac_file")

for index, row in legac_cat.iterrows():

    file_name = "legac_M{}_v3.6_spec1d_{}.fits".format(row["mask"], row["id"])
    # open the file using file_name
```